# change the frequency of a sine wave in realtime in python

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

I've got a side project on the go, which involves changing the tone of an audio signal in realtime. The tone is being generated with a sine wave, and my issue is that the tone jumps as it's being changed.

If you run this code, you'll hear the tone jump as it starts changing, and jump once again as its reached the target frequency (500hz).

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import math
import wave
import array
import pyaudio

freq=450.0
data_size=20000

frate = 11025.0
amp = 8000.0

target_freq = freq

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(2), channels=2, rate=int(frate), output=True)

for x in range(data_size):

    target_freq = 500 if x > 4000 else freq

    if abs(target_freq - freq) <= 0.1:
        delta = 0
    elif target_freq < freq:
        delta = -0.01
    elif target_freq > freq:
        delta = 0.01

    freq = freq + delta if delta else target_freq

    data = array.array('h')
    v = int(math.sin(2*math.pi*(freq)*(x/frate))*amp/2)
    data.append(v)
    data.append(v)
    stream.write(data.tostring())

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

I completely understand that the sine wave needs a phase shift to stop it from sliding as it's being updated.

Thanks.